# When i send a get request to a server on node js i get "Unexpected token in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js

When i started using node js everything was good and running smoothly. As soon as i tryed to connect to mongoDB the - "Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse() " started to appeared every single time  i was sending a get request from postman to the server. In addition, files that were already worked perfectly are no longer running and dont return any data, but as well return the same error of - "Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()".
The error dont refers to any specific line in the code.
what may cause this error ?

Comment: You probably have an error that is returning an HTML page. remove the parse for now and return what you get and see what it's returning.

Comment: The issue is that i did not put any parse at any stage of the code. Unless you meant  somthing else.

Comment: In order for us to diagnose your problem, you will have to provide the minimum amount of code for us to see.